# Treat external HD like internal

Tags: macos, external-disk, mount, hdd

Out of necessity I decided to migrate all my personal/work data to a new external hard drive (HFS, encrypted) and left the internal HD for the OS.

Because of the fact, that I am now fully reliant on this external HD for the iTunes/iPhoto libraries and numerous other things I need to ensure that this drive won't get accidentally ejected/erased and doesn't show up as an option e.g. in the Boot Camp installer creation wizard.

To make it clear - only this specific drive needs this special treatment, the rest (like flash drives) should be treated as usual.

Is it possible to target this via some Mount Point setting, perhaps?

Comment: @njboot I said nothing about booting from it. It's just a drive with one encrypted HFS partition containing my data. I want to prevent accidental ejection/unmounting/erasing. I don't want OS X to see it as an external drive, I need it to be seen as fixed, non-detachable.

Comment: how is it connected ?

Comment: @Buscar It's connected via USB

Comment: @Marco Did you already migrate your user to the external disk?

Comment: @klanomath My user account is not migrated, I don't need it to be on the external drive since I don't really store any data in my home folder. OS X's home folder structure is kind of clunky and I prefer to have more flexibility. The external drive is purely for data - just one encrypted partition with some stuff on it.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking possibly have a look at fstab or chflags. Although these methods may not achieve exactly what you need but they may help to avoid unwanted or accidental interaction with the external drive.

One caveat that I have found with chflags is that you don't seem to have Finder access to the disk unless you unhide it. It does support having an iPhoto Library on the external disk. I tried this by making an test iPhoto library on a disk without chflags hidden and then hiding it with chflags nohidden. iPhoto can access the disk but it does not show up anywhere besides the apps such as Disk Utility.

To see the chflags options do:

man chflags in the Terminal.app

Here are two articles relating to fstab and chflags that you might find interesting and possibly help you achieve what you have described:

http://www.macissues.com/2014/08/27/how-to-hide-a-hard-drive-partition-on-your-mac/
http://julipedia.meroh.net/2007/01/hide-volume-in-mac-os-x.html

As far as accidentally un-mounting goes I guess if you have something open on that drive the system will automatically protect it. You might be able to use a LaunchDaemon of some sort to detect requests to unmount a drive also. On the other hand, there is no protection against physically pulling out the cable.

I hope these help.

Comment: Well, hiding that disk is not an option, because I need constant access to my work files. However the idea with the LaunchDaemon is very good. I am wondering if there is a way to create an AppleScript, which would write (and overwrite) a hidden, empty ".blocked" file on that Volume (just like OS X does for other things, e.g. Time Machine setting) and keep it open all the time in some kind of empty daemon which would only "hog" this file without actually doing anything.